# Is there a prog lang with NOR op?

Tags: operators

An instructor counted it as a mistake when I listed NOR as a Boolean op found in prog langs. I'm hoping to get that point back with a citation.

Comment: why would you need a specific NOR operation?

Comment: @Femaref: NOR is one of those neat ops that you can construct any other operator out of.

Comment: Yes, which would be needed in gate design for CMOS based ICs. Where is the reason for it in a programming language? You already have all operators defined and compound a nor operation doing `!(a || b)`. There is no reason for a nor operation to exist except for  convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VHDL has `nor`: http://www.cs.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/operator.html

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think of that!

Comment: Thank you very much. I used your example, alas to no avail. My instructor is hopeless to say the least.

Comment: @user490735: oh well, it was worth a try ! `;-)`

Comment: @user490735: Why?? Doesn't he considers Verilog or VHDL languages?

Comment: When I brought this up, this instructor resorted to arbitrary deflections like that VHDL (after I pointed her to a wikipedia article about it) is a hardware language, and after I kept explaining that it's a programming language, she said that she was only concerned with the languages discussed in class (none actually, some were simply mentioned; it's a hopeless class). This only makes me appreciate you guys all the more.

Comment: @user490735: a good teacher, no matter how experienced, would have the confidence to accept that they might occasionally be wrong about something and be prepared to learn from their mistakes - it sounds like your instructor may be a little insecure about their abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, I don't believe. Of course, you can approximate it with `nor x y = !(x || y)`, but that's not much use to you.

`nor` tends to be used in hardware design [1], not so much software, but you're correct in calling it a boolean operator, and your instructor is mistaken in calling you mistaken on it.

[1] http://www.serve.net/buz/Notes.1st.year/HTML/C1/bits.005.html